# Can the height be changed if it is larger than the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change style using javascript
I want to do this
`style{height:100%}`
change this one
`style{height:auto}`
Change when it exceeds 100%,
If it is 100%, he cannot fill the window height.

Comment: you are probably looking for min-height:100%

Comment: Share how much have you tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript

```
elt.style.height= "100vh";
```

or CSS

```
.elt-class {height: 100vh;}
```

100vh is 100% of a view side of the current screen.

or you can use 100% height, but only in condition:

```
html, body, .all-parents-classes {min-height: 100%;}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;} /*fix browser standard paddings*/
```

Comment: I tried this, but it would exceed the height of the window when the element was wrapped inside.

Comment: I use article to wrap the section, but when the section exceeds the height of the article, he will exceed the artcile, and does not stretch him, extending the background color of the artcile

Comment: My english grammar is bad sorry

Comment: If it exceed the size with `100vh`, it could be caused by margins or paddings. Try `box-sizing: border-box;`.